# c# Controller won't accept utf-8 characters

Tags: c#, utf-8, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have a web API controller POST method that accepts incoming JSON. The posted JSON is UTF-8 encoded and sometimes contains extended ascii characters such as ¾ . Whenever these are included the parameter returns null.

A simple example:

```
    public void Post(Fruit fruit)
    {
        if (fruit == null)
        {//Post fails}
        }
    }

    public class Fruit
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
    }
```

Tested with powershell's Invoke-RestMethod:

```
$data = @"
{
  "name": "Orange",
   "size": "5¾ cm"
}
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Body $data -Uri "http://localhost:nnnnn/api/fruit" -Method POST -ContentType "application/json"
```

How can I set the encoding so that model is popuated ?

Comment: What about encryption of this type of data?

Comment: can you check if you see any model state errors?

Comment: How certain are you that it's *really* using UTF-8? Does the request *state* that it's using UTF_8? I suggest you have a look at what's going down the wire using Wireshark. Also note that "extended ASCII" is a fairly meaningless term, and should be avoided. Non-ASCII probably covers anything you can about here.

Comment: In general encodings are specified in the content-type header e.g. "application/json; charset=utf-8 " but setting that doesn't automatically encode the content correctly. As Jon says, you need to check the bytes going over the wire.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. Jon, I fiddled with Wireshark earlier unsuccessfully, so have been unable to answer the encoding question, although the developer concerned assures me that it is. In atempting to answer Kirans question, I built an MVC Controller, and that works fine ! Due to the nature of the app its not important which is used so I am going to leave it there. Thanks again.